# MFC How do you determine if ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI is for the menubar or toolbar?

Tags: c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I have a case where I want the menus to set the check on items using `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI`; however, on the toolbar I'm going to use a dropdown toolbar, so I only want to select the correct toolbar item and not change its checked state.

How do I determine if the `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` call is for the menu-bar or the toolbar?

Comment: Use different command IDs for the menu vs. the toolbar button, since it doesn't sound like they implement the same behaviors anyway.

Comment: The idea was a multiple option choice that could be selected via a drop down toolbar, but clicking on it really doesn't do anything (just a visual of the current option) , i may rethink what to do for the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the [`m_pMenu` member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccmdui-class?view=msvc-160#m_pmenu) of the handler's given `CCmdUI` parameter; if the routine was invoked for a menu item, that will be a valid `CMenu*` pointer; if not, it will be `NULL`:

```cpp
void CMyClass::OnUpdateHandler(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
   if (!pCmdUI->m_pMenu) {
       // NOT for a menu
   }
   else {
       // For a menu
   }
}
```